# Flask - конфигурация из объекта

Tags: python, flask

В общем то проблем с импортом из объекта нет, но возникает вопрос, откуда Flask узнаёт, где расположен объект, из которого нужно импортировать конфигурацию? Вот моя структура приложения:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   └── views.py
├── config.py
├── run.py
└── tmp
```

В __init__.py я просто пишу:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

Но ведь файл с конфигом находится на уровеь выше. Причём если переместить config.py в app, то импорт не удасться - ошибка объект не найден. Почему объект (модуль) config доступен только снаружи пакета?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__.py` инициализирует пакет **`app`**, который находится *на том же уровне, что и `config.py`*. Так что `config` на самом деле *не* снаружи, а на том же уровне, что и *пакет* `app`. Поэтому Flask обнаруживает файл с конфигом.

### Немного глубже

Посмотрим на исходники метода `from_object`:

```
def from_object(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, string_types):
        obj = import_string(obj)
        for key in dir(obj):
            if key.isupper():
                self[key] = getattr(obj, key)
```

Никакой магии тут не проиходит. Метод `import_string` принадлежит пакету [`werkzeug.utils`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py#L399). По сути, он просто пробует импортировать пакет/модуль/объект из разных мест, стандартными питоновскими способами, а значит все [правила импорта из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) сохраняются.